# Listen button outside of listview and modify the first item

Tags: android

I am learning android and this is my assignment of making music player interface. So far all is well but I stuck on the last part.

I want to `Play` (just changing the button icon) the first item in the `ListView` when hit the `Play All button which is outside of the`ListView`.

[image]

You can find entire project on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/q2amarket/musicmasti/src/8175fe3e76d8613eb0fb3906eb75190ce99c29fb). Although adding some required code here.

### activity_album.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Root Container - ConstraintLayout star -->
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DreamVoyage">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/album_cover_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/album_cover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/album_four" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#80000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/album_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Album Title"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/album_band"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/album_cover" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/album_band"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Album Band"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/album_play_all_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/album_title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/album_title" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/album_play_all_button"
            style="@style/AppTheme.RoundedCornerMaterialButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Play ALl"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- ScrollView start -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/playlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/album_cover_layout">

        <!-- playlist layout start -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/playlist_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </ListView><!-- playlist layout end -->

    </ScrollView><!-- ScrollView end -->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout><!-- Root Container - ConstraintLayout star -->
```

### SongAdapter.java

```
public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {

    int     playingIndex = -1;
    boolean currentTrack = false;

    public SongAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Song> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View             playlistItemView = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (playlistItemView == null) {
            playlistItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.playlist_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.albumCoverThumbnail = playlistItemView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_album_thumbnail);
            holder.songTitle = playlistItemView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_song_title);
            holder.songAlbumTitle = playlistItemView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_song_album_title);
            holder.songArtist = playlistItemView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_song_artist);
            holder.songPlayButton = playlistItemView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_play_button);

            playlistItemView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) playlistItemView.getTag();
        }

        final Song currentSong = getItem(position);

        // set data to the list item
        assert currentSong != null;
        holder.albumCoverThumbnail.setImageResource(currentSong.getSongAlbumCoverId());
        holder.songTitle.setText(currentSong.getSongTitle());
        holder.songAlbumTitle.setText(currentSong.getSongAlbumTitle());
        holder.songArtist.setText(currentSong.getSongSingers());

        // check the play status of the song item
        if (playingIndex == position) {
            holder.songPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
        } else {
            holder.songPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);
        }

        // set song button action
        holder.songPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.songPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);

                // pause current song on other click
                if (position == playingIndex) {
                    playingIndex = -1;
                } else {
                    playingIndex = position;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                // pause play current track
                if (currentTrack) {
                    holder.songPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);
                    currentTrack = !currentTrack;
                } else {
                    holder.songPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
                }
                currentTrack = !currentTrack;
            }
        });

        return playlistItemView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView   albumCoverThumbnail;
        TextView    songTitle;
        TextView    songAlbumTitle;
        TextView    songArtist;
        ImageButton songPlayButton;
    }
}
```

### HiddenTruth.java

```
public class HiddenTruth extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_album);

        // get view ids
        ImageView albumCoverImage = findViewById(R.id.album_cover);

        // get intent extras
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        // check if bundle in not null and containing value
        if (bundle != null) {

            String albumTitle = bundle.getString("album_two_title");
            String albumBand = bundle.getString("album_two_band");
            int albumCover = bundle.getInt("album_two_cover");

            albumCoverImage.setImageResource(albumCover);

            TextView albumTitleText = findViewById(R.id.album_title);
            TextView albumBandText = findViewById(R.id.album_band);

            albumTitleText.setText(albumTitle);
            albumBandText.setText(albumBand);

            ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();

            // get the thumbnail resource id
            int albumThumb = R.drawable.album_two_thumbnail;

            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "Hidden valley in the north", "Nicolo Viarina", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "The sea and the sky", "Mali nigara", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "Hidden valley in the north", "Nicolo Viarina", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "The sea and the sky", "Mali nigara", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "Hidden valley in the north", "Nicolo Viarina", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "The sea and the sky", "Mali nigara", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "Hidden valley in the north", "Nicolo Viarina", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "The sea and the sky", "Mali nigara", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "Hidden valley in the north", "Nicolo Viarina", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "The sea and the sky", "Mali nigara", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "Hidden valley in the north", "Nicolo Viarina", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "The sea and the sky", "Mali nigara", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "Hidden valley in the north", "Nicolo Viarina", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "The sea and the sky", "Mali nigara", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "Hidden valley in the north", "Nicolo Viarina", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "The sea and the sky", "Mali nigara", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "Hidden valley in the north", "Nicolo Viarina", albumThumb));
            songs.add(new Song(albumTitle, "The sea and the sky", "Mali nigara", albumThumb));

            SongAdapter songAdapter = new SongAdapter(this, 0, songs);

            ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.playlist_view);
            listView.setAdapter(songAdapter);

        } // @TODO move this brace after albumBand.setText(bundle.getString("album_two_band"));
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly you want ? either to click play all button which is outside listview or click individual item which are inside listview ?

Comment: @Umair I want when `Play All` clicked the first item should start. If you see my code in `SongAdapter.java`, I have already finished coding for individual item. Just looking for `Play All` button. Thanks

Comment: just pass a boolean value... `isPlayAll` to the constructor of the adapter.. and on Click of each item check if `position == 0 && isPlayAll` then play ..

Comment: @CodeLover you can use interfaces for that or use the technique which above comment told you.

Comment: @SantanuSur where I should pass the Boolean value? I am having trouble to get the Play All` button in the `SongAdapter`. Can you please explain me in more detail. Where and how I should get the button.

Comment: set the `onClickListener` for `playAll` button on the activity .... and onClick of `playAll` set the adapter of the songs again ..using the boolean value.. like :- 
`new SongAdapter(context,resource, objects, **isPlayAll**);`

Comment: @SantanuSur I see, let me try.

Comment: I appreciate your help but unable to make it. I am having trouble adding extra optional parameter in `SongAdapter` constructor

Comment: @SantanuSur done .. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

I have added another constructor to `SongAdapter`

```
public SongAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Song> objects, boolean isAllPlay) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    isAllPlayClicked = isAllPlay;
}
```

Than added below

```
// play first track on Play All button clicked
if (isAllPlayClicked) {
    playingIndex = 0;
    holder.songPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
    isAllPlayClicked = false;
    currentTrack = !currentTrack;
}
```

in activity file

```
// get the Play All button
Button playAll = findViewById(R.id.album_play_all_button);

// Play All button click event
playAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SongAdapter newAdapter = new SongAdapter(HiddenTruth.this, 0, songs, true);
        listView.setAdapter(newAdapter);
    }
});
```

I hope this will help someone.